# UPDATE information inside database where id = 2019

Tags: c#, sql-update, buttonclick

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xcon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter xadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "UPDATE dbo.SysX SET fp = @fp, sd = @sd, sf= @sf" +
    "WHERE id = 2019", xcon);
    command.Parameters.Add("@fp", SqlDbType.Int, 5, textBox1.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@sd", SqlDbType.Int, 40, textBox2.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@sf", SqlDbType.Int, 40, textBox3.Text);
    xadapter.UpdateCommand = command;
    xcon.Close();
}
```

looking to update information inside data base where id = 2019 on click of button. Nothings happens and do not get error... i am not using data table just updating

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use an Update Statement in SQLDataAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861746/how-to-use-an-update-statement-in-sqldataadapter)

Comment: Remove the SqlDataAdapter and execute the *command*, with `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: You have nicely filled out an sqlcommand but you never told it to go off and do work. You did all the prep, even nicely using parameters.. but you never told it to do it.

Comment: Convert those  `textboxN.Text` into integers.

Answer (score 1):

1) You missed Execute the query
2) Convert to the correct type
3) In addition, I'd put ID as a parameter too.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    xcon.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter xadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    @"UPDATE dbo.SysX SET fp = @fp, sd = @sd, sf= @sf
    WHERE id = @id", xcon);
    command.Parameters.Add("@fp", SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add("@sd", SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add("@sf", SqlDbType.Int, Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
    command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 2019);
    // next command !!!
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    xadapter.UpdateCommand = command;
    xcon.Close();
}
```